# Long underline tag, not <u>

Tags: html

Ho do i achieve the grey underline in the welcome part of the website? I forgot the tag, it basically creates a line all the way across the page/div/table whatever you want.

[The website(where it says welcome to CLAN):](http://www.clan.org.au/)

Comment: Could the tag be `<hr>`?

Comment: Yes that's it, could someone enlighten me as to why the question was downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, though I considered it. This is a pretty damned lazy question, even ignoring the fact that you called it a "long underline".

Comment: I felt as if it was a bit of a nooby question, and it i just forgot something, that required a 30 second answer. I didn't think it needed to be perfectly formatted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well, everyone's got to learn _somehow_, eh?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [Horizontal Rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr):

```
<hr>
```

And it looks like this:

---

You can also [style it using CSS](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html) (as Stack Overflow have done), something like this:

```
hr {
    color: red;
    background-color: red;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the tag you are looking for is an: [`<hr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/hr)

Answer (score -2):

```
<hr>
```

You can use 4 attributes, that are not supported in HTML5.

- align
- noshade
- size
- width

I use this on my website: means 99% of screen-width and size 1.

```
<hr noshade size=1 width="99%">
```

Please read the articles below to understand you problem:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Comment: -1 for the W3Schools link - it's discouraged on Stack Overflow. See why here: http://w3fools.com

Comment: "W3Schools.com is not affiliated with the W3C in any way. Members of the W3C have asked W3Schools to explicitly disavow any connection in the past, and they have refused to do so. W3Schools frequently publishes inaccurate or misleading content". See also: [Will I be downvoted for giving a W3Schools link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120025/195862)

Comment: "That being said, I think some people would downvote on sight anything that they noticed referring people to W3Schools, regardless of context / correctness." See at first:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link

Comment: Indeed, which is what I have done... as I said, W3Schools links are discouraged on [SO].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26501/discussion-between-stepo-and-danny-beckett)

Comment: (If you were to remove the link, I'd remove my downvote, in case that wasn't already clear)... no time to chat.

Comment: Ok, as you want...I didn't find content of my link faulty, so I think it's relevant source. In the future I'll avoid w3cschools as you said.

Comment: So that *particular* article might not be faulty, 20 other links on that page (that a user could click) might well be.

Comment: You don't get it... peace out.

Comment: Very depressing busy Mr. XY ^^

Comment: @DannyBeckett - I think you're being quite unfair to this user. Yes w3schools isn't a great site but there's nothing hellishly wrong with the explanation on that page. Also Stepo did initially link to w3.org and added the w3schools link as a supplemental. I don't think this deserves a downvote and you're being a bit bloody minded.

Comment: @Kev Feel free to delete the comments on this answer, but I'm going with [consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120029/195862).

Comment: I personally learnt from W3schools, which , according to you all. Would make my knowledge tainted. And therefore void? I'm not experienced enough to say if it's faulty, however all of their lessons have helped me alot.

Comment: And i've also been banned from asking questions apparently. Which is quite dissapointing, as i forgot my old account details, which had a larger reputation. And i do believe the ban applies to all of my machines on my network. I suppose i will not be seeing any of you any longer.